# Rails. Missing partial error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Userdata#index
Showing /home/bacho/Desktop/RoR/mainapp/app/views/userdata/index.html.erb where line #32 raised:

Missing partial userdata/_userdatatr, application/_userdatatr with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/bacho/Desktop/RoR/mainapp/app/views"
```

I have 2 partial files in `views/userdata/` folder with identical content

1. `_userdatatr.html.erb`
2. `_userdatat.html.erb`

when I try (`@language== 'ru'`) to render first file I receive this error. but second file render works fine.

```
<% if @language== 'ru' %>
  <%= render 'userdatatr', obj: @userdata %>  <!-- receiving error here -->
<% else %>
  <%= render 'userdatat', obj: @userdata %>   <!-- works fine -->
<% end %>
```

Environment is ubuntu with Rails 4.2.5.1

Comment: Do you have `_userdatatr.html.erb` in your application?

Comment: views/application/ ? I dont have such folder

Comment: can you provide full file path

Comment: /home/bacho/Desktop/RoR/mainapp/app/views/userdata/_userdatatr.thml.erb

Comment: file extension is wrong its  **_userdatatr.html.erb**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the leading underscore character: partials are named with a leading underscore to distinguish them from regular views. In your case its **_userdatatr.html.erb**.

As per your comment, you have a wrong file extenstion, so please used suggested extention i.e. **.html.erb**